after updating to `Flutter Channel stable, 3.22.0` `flutter build` works but the build using the Xcode project doesn't work anymore
after updating to Flutter Channel stable, 3.22.0 flutter build works but the build using the Xcode project doesn't work anymore.
the error is:
/Users/fractale/CommercialProjects/fcp_library_cleaner/macos/Flutter/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.swift:8:8 No such module 'desktop_drop'

The strange thing for me is that the command line build work without any issue so I'm not sure what is going on.
I deleted macos/Podfile.lock macos/Pods/ then run pod install and pop update and have the following text:
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing FlutterMacOS (1.0.0)
Installing desktop_drop (0.0.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Runner/Configs/AppInfo.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Runner/Configs/AppInfo.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Runner/Configs/AppInfo.xcconfig`).

I have a few warning bug I'm not sure if they are relevant and desktop_drop 0.0.1 is installed but   desktop_drop: ^0.4.4  is normally used (but I imagine there a difference between pod version and flutter package?
I'm not sure how to solve this...

Solution: Make sure that you open xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj. xcworkspace - contains information about pods.
